# Drag and Drop multiple select with options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've two multiple select with options. I want drag and drop options from one multiple select element to other.

The problem is i guess multiple select not allow to drag. Now I'm trying to create a new draggable element on click on any option and append it to body. It's working fine. But the problem is I'm not able to start drag my element when i click and start drag on option. I've to again click and start drag my draggable element.

Is there any event to start drag? so that i can trigger on click of option after create new element? So that it feel like my option is dragging.

**NOTE: I've to use only multiple select in my case. I can't use jQuery UI sortable or other kinda widget here.**

**It's what i'm trying to do. It's rough idea now. I'll refactor it after solution**

```
$(document).on('mousedown', 'select option', function(e) {
    var self = $(this);
    var offset = self.offset();
    var draggableDiv = $('<div />').prop('id', 'draggable').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: offset.left,
        top: offset.top,
        width: self.width(),
        height: self.height(),
        cursor: 'default',
        background: '#ff0',
        opacity: 0.5
    }).text(self.text());
    $('body').append(draggableDiv);

    draggableDiv.draggable({
        revert: true,
        containment: 'window'
    });

    // function to start drag goes here
    draggableDiv.trigger('dragstart');
});
```

Comment: Have a look i update my question

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start

Comment: seems you  want pass click event to newly created element

Comment: try `draggableDiv.trigger(e)`

Comment: getting error "too much recursion"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed target of event, before pass it to draggable, also fixed position (see comments)

```
$(document).on('mousedown', 'select option', function(e) {
    var self = $(this);
    var offset = self.offset();
    var draggableDiv = $('<div />').prop('id', 'draggable').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: e.pageX,   // <-HERE
        top:  e.pageY,
        width: self.width(),
        height: self.height(),
        cursor: 'default',
        background: '#ff0',
        opacity: 0.5
    }).text(self.text());
    $('body').append(draggableDiv);

    draggableDiv.draggable({
        revert: true,
        containment: 'window'
    });
    e.target=draggableDiv.get(0);  // <-HERE
    // function to start drag goes here
    draggableDiv.trigger(e);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3zHjt/)

[other demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Y5GWq/) - looks little more accurate for me

Comment: Thanks Man, You're Rock Star!! Can you pleases let me know meaning or logic of "e.target = draggableDiv.get(0)"

Comment: the target was `<option>` an become newly created `div` so event will be passed correct, that needed just because you binded your event listener to the document, and os it recursive fired

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".droppable").droppable({
       drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $list = $(this);
        $helper = ui.helper;
        $($helper).removeClass("selected");
        var $selected = $(".selected");                 
        if($selected.length > 1){                       
            moveSelected($list,$selected);
        }else{
            moveItem(ui.draggable,$list);
}                                       
        }, tolerance: "touch"
         });

             $(".draggable").draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                helper: "clone",
                cursor: "move",
                drag: function(event,ui){
                    var $helper = ui.helper;
                    $($helper).removeClass("selected");
                    var $selected = $(".selected"); 
                    if($selected.length > 1){   
                        $($helper).html($selected.length + " items");
                    }                                       
                }
             });

            function moveSelected($list,$selected){
                $($selected).each(function(){
                    $(this).fadeOut(function(){
                        $(this).appendTo($list).removeClass("selected").fadeIn();
                    });                 
                });             
            }

            function moveItem( $item,$list ) {
                $item.fadeOut(function() {
                    $item.find(".item").remove();
                    $item.appendTo( $list ).fadeIn();
                });
            }

            $(".item").click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass("selected");
            });

        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/caferdo/k5XJv/3/

Here is an example